# Работа промисов

Tags: javascript, promise

Добрый Вечер. Наткнулся на такой пример с промисами :

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(1);
});

function logger(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

promise
  .then(logger)
  .then(logger(2))
  .then(() => logger(3));
```

В результате на выходе результат - 2, 1, 3. Правильно ли я понимаю, что перед тем, как начинать выполнять данный код, с начала отдается приоритет вызову функции logger ? Именно поэтому в результате с начала идет 2 ? Функция logger, возвращает undefined, а в консоль пишет 2. Затем, после выполнения промиса, после первого then (который вернул вместо промиса undefined), в консоль запишется 1, а уж затем вернется 3.

Comment: Promise тут ни при чём. Просто во втором случае, вы передаёте функции аргумент, который необходимо вычислить. Это как `var f2 = logger(2); p.then(f2);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Promise нужен для выполнения действий со значением, которого на момент определения действий может ещё не быть. Это чтобы было немножко понятнее, какова цель всего происходящего здесь.

Ещё обращу внимание, что существующие реализации JS однопоточны и переключения в пределах одной исполняющей среды (скажем, вебворкеры я считаю отдельными средами) происходят только между функциями, после завершения выполнения каждой. Разумеется, функции внутри себя могут *синхронно* (непосредственно) вызывать другие функции, но многое в JS API опирается на *асинхронные* вызовы, которые лишь приводят к добавлению в очередь событий и, когда-нибудь, обработку циклом событий.

Ну да к делу.

Вывод у вас происходит при **вызове** функции `logger`. Посмотрим, когда она вызывается.

**Сначала выполняется наружный код.** Определение цепочки промисов. Пока выполнение этого участка не дойдёт до самого конца, никакая другая функция вызвана по какому-либо событию (вроде разрешения промиса, что здесь происходит) не будет.

```
promise
  .then(logger)
  .then(logger(2))
  .then(() => logger(3));
```

- В первом вызове `then` аргументы разрешаются в значения напрямую, без вычислений. *Никаких вызовов `logger` там не происходит.* Пока что.
- Во втором вызове `then` аргумент уже **выражение**, требующее вычисления перед передачей: вызов функции `logger`. **Тут-то и вызывается `logger(2)` и выводится `2`.** А возвращается из `logger`... ничего, что снаружи видно как `undefined`, которое функцией не является а потому приводит к "сквозному пробрасыванию" результата в следующий `then` (если таковой, как здесь, имеется), поскольку:

  > If the first argument is omitted or provided a non-function, the new Promise that is created simply adopts the fulfillment state of the Promise that then is called on (if it becomes fulfilled).
  >
  > Если первый аргумент не передан, или в нём передана не функция, то промис наследует состояние разрешения у промиса, на котором then был вызван (если он разрешается).
  >
  > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

  Я б сказал, что игнорирование типа аргумента в `then` это грубый хак, сбивающий с толку и склоняющий к злоупотреблениям, но у него могут быть свои мотивы. Без большой необходимости кормить в `then` не-функции не стоит.
- В третьем вызове аргумент  является **функциональным выражением** ([стрелочной функцией](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), если точно), но для его вычисления *вызовы `logger` не нужны*, т. к. его результатом является функция, которая при **вызове** (но не создании!) вызывает `logger` и выводит что-то в консоль. А на этом этапе эта функция лишь создалась.

**А потом уже управление переходит внутрь,** поскольку промис требует запуска, его событие ждёт своей очереди на обработку. В зависимости от другого выполняющегося в той же машине JS-кода может быть и не сразу, но в рамках примера другого кода нет, так что тут — сразу внутрь цепочки.

- Сначала вызывается функция из конструктора `Promise`. Она приводит к разрешению промиса со значением `1`.
- Затем вызывается `logger` с аргументом, полученным из прошлого промиса: **получается `logger(1)`. А потому происходит вывод `1`**, а промис разрешается со значением `undefined` (т. к. функция ничего не вернула).

  > When a value is simply returned from within a then lambda, it will effectively return `Promise.resolve(<value returned by whichever handler was called>)`.
- Затем сталкиваемся с пустым промисом, образованным без функции... фиг знает, что там внутри ещё происходит, но результат прошлого разрешения промиса (`undefined`) просто считается результатом и у этого и передаётся далее, состояние промиса (разрешился) при этом сохраняется.
- Затем функция `() => logger(3)` вызывается с аргументом `undefined`, но JS наплевать на лишние аргументы и в результате успешно выполняется тело функции, **выполняется `logger(3)` и выводится `3`.**

Comment: То есть получается обработка цепочки происходит не сразу, а с начала идет что то вроде "анализа" этой цепочки. После просмотра всей цепи, уже непосредственно отрабатывает callback-функции внутри цепи.

Comment: @Drylozav ну, сначала выполняется непосредственно код "снаружи", весь. Пока он весь не выполнится, никаких асинхронных вызовов (каковой делает каждый промис, возвращаемый конструктором или `then`'ом) не происходит. Теоретически, в асинхронном вызове цепь можно и достроить, хоть у вас это и не делается.

Comment: А можно про это где то почитать ? Я пытаюсь найти что то, про определение цепочки промисов (где написано "Сначала выполняется наружный код").

Comment: @Drylozav см. замечание об однопоточности. Тело всей программы можно считать одной большой функцией без названия. А все асинхронные вызовы, которые в ней делаются, будут обработаны только когда её выполнение завершится. Где почитать об этом, сходу даже не скажу, пойду совершу ритуал призыва JS-спецов, может они подскажут.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что речь идет о Microtask/Macrotask queue ? То есть компилятор проходит по всему коду и определяет куда запихнуть различные действия (вызовы функции, ожидания выполнения промиса и т.д.). Значит вызов функции logger попадет в Macrotask , а выполнение промиса в Microtask. И пока Macrotask не будет пустым, callback-функции в then выполняться не будут (т.к. они находятся в Microtask queue).

Comment: @Drylozav тут даже деление на micro/macro не нужно (для понимания; оно не влияет на поведение), т. к. все исполняемые вызовы строго упорядочены, они выстроены по зависимостям в линию. Сначала тело всей программы, а после цепочка промисов, определённая в нём.

Comment: Я просто хочу понять, где про это можно прочитать. Вот и пытаюсь копать в сторону микро/макро.

Comment: @Drylozav,  Если с английским языком нет проблем посмотрите вот этот доклад: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=630s

Comment: Спасибо, уже как раз сегодня на него набрел, когда пытался найти какую-либо информацию.